# Throw an error back to jQuery from an MVC HttpPost

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method in a controller that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UnfavoriteEvent(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var rows = _connection.Execute("DELETE UserEvent WHERE UserID = (SELECT up.UserID FROM UserProfile up WHERE up.UserName = @UserName) AND EventID = @EventID",
            new { EventID = id, UserName = User.Identity.Name });
        if (rows != 1)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            Response.Status = "There was an unknown error updating the database.";
            //throw new HttpException(500, "There was an unknown error updating the database.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Response.Status = ex.Message;
        //throw new HttpException(500, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And as you can see I've tried a couple of different ways to throw this error back. In the JavaScript I have the following block to call this method:

```
var jqXHR;
if (isFavorite) {
    jqXHR = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Account/UnfavoriteEvent',
        data: { id: $("#EventID").val() }
    });
}
else {
    jqXHR = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Account/FavoriteEvent',
        data: { id: $("#EventID").val() }
    });
}

jqXHR.error = function (data) {
    $("#ajaxErrorMessage").val(data);
    $("#ajaxError").toggle(2000);
};
```

Now, what I want to do is get the error that occurs thrown back to the `jqXHR.error` function so that I can handle it properly.

Currently the code that is uncommented throws an exception saying that the text I'm placing in `Status` is not allowed, and the commented code actually returns the standard error page as the response (not surprising really).

So, I have a couple of questions:

1. How do I throw the error properly?
2. What does the `Response.Status` property do?

Thanks all!

Comment: Since you're catching a generic exception, I wouldn't send the specific message back to the client. This could end up being sensitive information about your application. If you catch custom domain exceptions where you're in control of the message you can send them to the client, but for the generic exception you should send a generic message.

Comment: @BZink, very good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be abled to get the response status from the javascript side, doing the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Account/UnfavoriteEvent',
    data: { id: $("#EventID").val() },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // jqXHR.status contains the Response.Status set on the server
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // jqXHR.status contains the Response.Status set on the server
    }});
```

As you can see, you must pass the function for `error` to the `ajax` function... in you example, you are setting the function to the `error` property of `jqXHR` with no effect at all.

**Documentation on ajax events**

- [jQuery - Ajax Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events)

jQuery docs say that the error string will come in the `errorThrown` parameter.

**Do not use Response**

Instead, you should return `HttpStatusCodeResult`:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UnfavoriteEvent(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var rows = _connection.Execute("DELETE UserEvent WHERE UserID = (SELECT up.UserID FROM UserProfile up WHERE up.UserName = @UserName) AND EventID = @EventID",
            new { EventID = id, UserName = User.Identity.Name });
        if (rows != 1)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, "There was an unknown error updating the database.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: That definitely got me into the error method in the JavaScript, so thanks! But the error string I want isn't in the `Response.Status`. What am I doing wrong server-side and how do I get that simple message down to the client?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Response.StatusDescription`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statusdescription.aspx). On the jQuery side, use `jqXHR.fail(function(){})`.